# Why is this.value undefined when getting value of images?

Tags: javascript, html, image, this

New to coding, please be gentle. This has to be done with **pure JavaScript**, due to limitations by our class. At the moment, all I'm trying to do is `console.log()` the value of the image clicked by the user. In this instance, it's either `value="0"` for "Rock", `value="1"` for "Paper" or `value="2"` for "Scissors". I'm unexperienced with using `this.value`, and I'm wondering if I can pass the value of the clicked image as a parameter to the function called "check()".

**HTML**

```
<img src="img/rock.png" alt="Rock" id="rock" value="0" onclick="check(this.value)">
<img src="img/paper.png" alt="Paper" id="paper" value="1" onclick="check(this.value)">
<img src="img/scissors.png" alt="Scissors" id="scissors" value="2" onclick="check(this.value)">
```

**JavaScript (no jQuery)**

```
function check(inputValue) {
            console.log(inputValue);
        }
```

I expect the output to be either 0, 1 or 2 depending on which image was clicked by the user. At the moment, all I'm getting is `undefined`.

Comment: Images don't have a value attribute. You'd probably be better off using a data attribute.

Comment: Also, avoid using obtrusive event handlers.

Comment: data-attribute is not needed, @j08691

Comment: @JavascriptDev Sure, not "needed", but I'd argue that it satisfies the more important condition of "best practice". For example, you could access the attribute instead of the property, but why go through that when the standard presents a simpler method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because images don't have a `value` attribute, this will always come back as `undefined`. An alternative would be to use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access). These can be retrieved using `this.dataset.<attributeName>`.

For example, `data-value` would be accessed by doing `this.dataset.value`.

```js
function check(inputValue) {
  console.log(inputValue);
}
```

```html
<img src="img/rock.png" alt="Rock" id="rock" data-value="0" onclick="check(this.dataset.value)">
<img src="img/paper.png" alt="Paper" id="paper" data-value="1" onclick="check(this.dataset.value)">
<img src="img/scissors.png" alt="Scissors" id="scissors" data-value="2" onclick="check(this.dataset.value)">
```

Answer (score 3):

Images don't have a value attribute. You'd probably be better off using a data attribute.

```js
function check(inputValue) {
  console.log(inputValue.dataset.value);
}
```

```html
<img src="img/rock.png" alt="Rock" id="rock" data-value="0" onclick="check(this)">
<img src="img/paper.png" alt="Paper" id="paper" data-value="1" onclick="check(this)">
<img src="img/scissors.png" alt="Scissors" id="scissors" data-value="2" onclick="check(this)">
```